# is it possible to serial object to json in one function in dart

Tags: dart

In Java, we can serial any object like this:

```
Object anyObj = new Object();

String json = JSON.tostring(anyObj);
```

but in Dart, we must define toJson method like this in every single Object:

```
import 'dart:convert';

String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());
```

and define toMap:

```
Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {}
```

any simple way? Image if the system has 10000+ objects, are we write toJson function for every object? Is it possible to serial object to json like Java way in Dart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most Java libraries that provide serialization of arbitrary objects rely on runtime reflection to know what fields are present on an object (and their types, etc).

Runtime reflection is technically possible in Dart (using `dart:mirrors`) but the library is unstable and is not available on all platforms (notably runtime reflection is disabled in Flutter).

The idiomatic Dart way to do this is with code generation. In general, you add the required annotations/etc, then run `flutter pub run build_runner build` to use the `build_runner` package to generate extra code.

A couple of popular libraries are:

1. `json_serializable` is useful if you have a model class that you want to add `toJson()` and `fromJson()` methods to:

```dart
@JsonSerializable  // marks the class for json code generation
class Dog {
  final String name;
  final int age;
  Dog(this.name, this.age);

  // boilerplate for generated implementations
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$DogToJson(this);  
  factory Dog.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$DogFromJson(json);
}
```

2. `built_value` is a more all-encompassing approach. The main purpose of the library is to provide deep immutability for model classes, similar to Kotlin's `data class`. However, it also provides good serialization support out of the box. There is a fair amount of boilerplate, but it can definitely be worth it (especially if you use the vscode plugin to write it for you):

```dart
abstract class Dog extends Built<Dog, DogBuilder> {
  Dog._();
  factory Dog([void Function(DogBuilder) updates]) = _$Dog;

  String get name;
  int get age;
}
```

You can then use this code like:

```dart
final dog = Dog((b) {
  b.name = 'name';
  b.age = 123;
});
final helloDog = dog.rebuild((b) => b.name = 'hello');
```

This blog post goes through serialization in detail: https://medium.com/dartlang/darts-built-value-for-serialization-f5db9d0f4159#.h12y94wu7

Both libraries are maintained by Google